# Can't import "bootstrap-select" in app.scss in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm doing following:

```
npm install bootstrap-select

npm run dev
```

in app.scss

```
// Bootstrap Select

@import "node_modules/bootstrap-select/sass/bootstrap-select.scss";
```

In console it says:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: `$(...).selectpicker` is not a function
>   TypeError: `$(...).selectpicker` is not a function

I can see it installed bootstrap-select, how do I import it correctly?

Comment: Does `@import "../../../node_modules/...` work?

Comment: This dosen't work either @import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/sass/bootstrap-select.scss";

Comment: and i just did the same with @import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it's three folders up, changed my comment

Comment: Dosen't work either

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"> works ofc

Comment: That's how you import `bootstrap-select`/`font-awesome` into your `app.scss`. Your error states that you didn't include the javascript in your `app.js`.

Comment: How do i include it the right way? just in the footer like with cdn?

Comment: You could add `require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select');` to your `resources/assets/js/app.js` and include `app.js` at the end of the page, but if the `cdn` version is working why not use that

Comment: Works with this line and adding app.js to footer as you said thx alot sir require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js');

Comment: can you submit an answer?

Comment: Try `@import "~bootstrap-select/sass/bootstrap-select.scss";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `/resources/assets/sass/app.scss` import bootstrap-select:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/sass/bootstrap-select.scss";
```

You also need to import `bootstrap-select.js` to `resources/assets/js/app.js` make it work:

```
require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select');
```

Answer (score 4):

Its possible to add [Bootstrap-Select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) without the complete path:

```
require('bootstrap-select');
require('bootstrap-select/js/i18n/defaults-de_DE');
```

```
@import '~bootstrap-select/sass/bootstrap-select.scss';
```

Comment: In my case, i had an "Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined' error, so I had to put the bootstrap in window first like this:
window.bootstrap = require('./bootstrap') in my app.js. Just in case if anybody have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

in laravel 5.7

in app.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap-select/sass/bootstrap-select.scss';
```

in app.js

```
require('../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min');
```

Answer (score 1):

npm install bootstrap-select

npm run dev

---

In resources\assets\sass\app.scss

@import "node_modules/bootstrap-select/sass/bootstrap-select.scss";

---

in resources\assets\js\app.js

require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js');

---

Add app.scss in head

Add app.js before end of body