# How to get bootstrap-select css into Laravel public folder

Tags: php, laravel

I installed `bootstrap-select` package using `npm`. I can see that in `node-modules` dir of my `Laravel` project.

I have added following entry to `master.blade.php`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-select.css') }}">
```

However when I run `php artisan serve` on my local machine, and go to browser I can see following error in the console:

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of
>   404 (Not Found) (bootstrap-select.css, line 0)
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/bootstrap-select.css

I am using `Laravel Framework 5.7.28`

Any clues much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/412#issuecomment-280683564) comment, you need to link the CSS file in your `app.scss` using the following syntax:

```
@import "~module-name/path/to/css.css";
```

then fire `npm run dev` which should compile your assets again. Also:

> The tilde (~) tells Webpack that we're not looking for that jquery.filer.css file relatively to app.scss. Instead, we want to look within node_modules.

It will compile everything into a single `app.css` file which you can then include, no need to individually load the `bootstrap-select.css` file.

Comment: When doing this then you will need to include `app.css` and not `bootstrap-select.css` since this will bundle them all together

Comment: @apokryfos yep, I thought that was clear but I'll clarify, thanks.

Comment: Thanks will give this a try. BTW I forgot to ask about bootstrap-select.js file. Will that be handled something similarly?

Comment: @AkshayLokur IIRC, your need to `require` the JS file into `resources\assets\js\app.js` and then run `npm run dev` to regenerate your `app.js` which should now include your bundled `app.js` with the `bootstrap-select` JS file..

Comment: @Script47: Great after following your instructions, 404 error is gone; BUT now I can't see the dropdown menus which were styled using "bootstrap-select" and also the JS function "selectpicker()" seems to be unavailable. After Googling a bit, folks say JQuery should load before "app.js". Any clue if this what I need to ensure and where this ordering happens? Sorry it may be a very rookie question but Laravel is overwhelming to start with!

Comment: No worries, got above one sorted out. This answer here was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913858/cant-import-bootstrap-select-in-app-scss-in-laravel